# Solving it in different ways

Tags: word-choice

Do "...solve this problem in different ways" and "there are some ways for solving this problem" sound natural?

"A lot of people aren't as healthy as their parents and grandparents used to be. People can solve this problem in different ways. There are some ways for solving this problem. People should do sport activities."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"solve this problem in different ways" sounds natural. "there are some ways for solving this problem" makes sense but does not sound natural. Instead you could phrase it as "there are several ways to solve this problem" or "there are different ways to solve this problem" or "there are some different ways this problem can be solved".

A common way to phrase the whole sentence would be "This problem can be solved in several different ways."